# Is there a way I can make users to pay first before making a post on a Django website?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

**This is my model**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import reverse


class Escort(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    ethnicity = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    orientation = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    area = models.TextField()
    skin_color = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    hair_color = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    services = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + '~' + str(self.author)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('escort-details', args=(str(self.id)))
```

**These are my views**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView
from .models import Escort



#def home(request):
    #return render(request, 'home.html',{})


class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Escort
    template_name = 'home.html'

class EscortDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Escort
    template_name = 'escort_details.html'

class AddEscortView(CreateView):
    model = Escort
    template_name = 'add_escort.html'
    fields = '__all__'
```

**These are my urls**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

from .views import HomeView, EscortDetailView, AddEscortView

urlpatterns = [
    #path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name="home"),
    path('escort/<int:pk>', EscortDetailView.as_view(), name="escort-details"),
    path('postad/', AddEscortView.as_view(), name="add-escort"),
    
]
```

**I also have four templates for the four views**

What I am basically doing is to create a website to advertise escort services. I want a user to sign up/sign in and click on the link "PostAd" and be redirected to a page with an escort form. After filling in all the information for an escort (escort model), the user will be required to pay first before the advert/post appears live on the homepage (ul of escorts will be organized using HTML in the homepage). Who can advise me from here, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want users to have an account and log in, then you need [authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/). If you would like to limit what a user can see and do, you need permissions. Django provides a built-in system for this.

Here is an example tutorial: [Django Tutorial Part 8: User authentication and permissions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication)

Note that by default Django's permission system only handles model-level permissions, i. e. a user can be given permission to edit a model type, for instance. If you would like to have permissions for model instances, you need to look into object-level permissions.